# How to change version of Ruby being run in TextWrangler?

Tags: ruby, textwrangler

I have Ruby 1.9.2 installed on my system (Mac OS X 10.7.4).

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]
```

When I use TextWrangler to run the following simple code:

> puts RUBY_VERSION

The output is "1.8.7".

How do I get TextWrangler to run the newer version? Thanks.

Comment: How did you install your ruby 1.9?

Comment: @Casper Honestly, I can't remember how.

Comment: Well OSX comes with ruby pre-installed, so that is what textwrangler is running. It's probably in `/usr/bin`. You could try and rename it to `ruby_old` or something like that and see if that picks up the new ruby. Also run `which ruby` on the command line to see where the 1.9 ruby is coming from. You can also try and modify your `PATH` so that the 1.9 ruby location is before `/usr/bin` in the path. Although why the path is different for textwrangler is a bit of a mystery. Perhaps you installed 1.9 using rvm.